# pandas.Series.replace not working with yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, yfinance

I'm having issues to remove the dollar symbol from a Series after importing data from Yahoo Finance (yfinance). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
import yfinance as yf

start_date = '2016-01-01'

yf_eth_df = yf.download('ETH-USD',start_date, today)
yf_eth_df = yf_eth_df.reset_index()


yf_eth_df.tail()
```

I've created a custom column to get the variation in percentage between the Open value and the Highest value.

The output is:

```
    Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume  variation_open_high
0   2017-11-09  $308.64 $329.45 $307.06 $320.88 $320.88 893249984   $6.32
1   2017-11-10  $320.67 $324.72 $294.54 $299.25 $299.25 885985984   $1.25
2   2017-11-11  $298.59 $319.45 $298.19 $314.68 $314.68 842300992   $6.53
3   2017-11-12  $314.69 $319.15 $298.51 $307.91 $307.91 1613479936  $1.40
4   2017-11-13  $307.02 $328.42 $307.02 $316.72 $316.72 1041889984  $6.51
```

For some reason, the data frame is being created with the `$` symbol. I want to remove it from my last column using `yf_eth_df['variation_open_high'] = yf_eth_df['variation_open_high'].replace("$", '')` but it is not working.

Comment: I added a comment there. It did not work as expected unfortunately. This is something I have never seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Series.replace` only replaces values that fully match. To replace substrings use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
yf_eth_df['variation_open_high'] = yf_eth_df['variation_open_high'].str.replace("$", '', regex=False)
```

Note that after removing the dollar sign the values are still strings. It seems that you want them as floats, so you have to explicitly convert them

```
yf_eth_df['variation_open_high'] = ( 
    yf_eth_df['variation_open_high'].str.replace("$", '', regex=False)
                                    .astype(float)
)
```

Comment: Ok. I realized I forgot to mention something in my first post. The values are all `numpy.float64` and it displays the `$` sign. It's weird. Try running that code on your machine. You'll see that you'll get the error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

So I decided to merge your idea with my: `yf_eth_df['variation_open_high'] = yf_eth_df['variation_open_high'].astype(str).str.replace("$", '', regex=False)`

it worked! But, when I transformed it back to float, the dollar sign returns. I've never seen something like that.

Comment: @MarceloOliveira it's impossible that the values are `numpy.float64` and at the same time they contain the dollar sign. Are you running the code on a jupyter notebook? It seems that you are running multiple times the same cell.

Comment: I changed some libs I was using and started from scratch. It is working now. It's serious. I don't know what was going on, but your solution and this discussion helped me to understand.

Thanks, man!

Comment: In time, I found the problem. The file I was working with had this line of code: `pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format`. I'll talk to my colleagues tomorrow.

Thanks again, bro!

Comment: @MarceloOliveira No problem! I'm glad you were able to solve the problem in the end ;) That line of code explains the issue that you were having! It makes sense, because internally the values are still floats, but are displayed as strings with the dollar sign.